# Display Query result of one table in another table for a View?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

The kpiRecord table stores all user-submitted KPI data. The kpiMaster table stores general data about each KPI - i.e. name, department, whether they have a Target or Critical No. etc.

In my Index View, I'd like to display all records from the kpiRecord table. However, because this table only stores a KPI Number ("kpiNo") , for this column I want to retrieve the KPI Name ("kpiName") from the kpiMaster table and display this instead.

How can I query my kpiMaster table and display the results within my kpiRecord table in Index? (e.g. SELECT kpiMaster.kpiName WHERE kpiRecord.kpiNo == kpiMaster.kpiNo)

Controller.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index() { 

   var tables = new KpiViewModel {
       vmKpiMaster = _context.kpirep_dev_kpiMaster.ToList(),
       vmKpiGoal = _context.kpirep_dev_kpiGoal.Where(kpiGoal => kpiGoal.isActive).ToList(),
       vmKpiRecord = _context.kpirep_dev_kpiRecord.Where(kpiRecord => kpiRecord.isActive).ToList()
   };

   return View(tables);
}
```

kpiViewModel.cs

```
public class KpiViewModel {

   public IEnumerable<kpiMaster> vmKpiMaster { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<kpiGoal> vmKpiGoal { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<kpiModel> vmKpiRecord { get; set; }
   }
```

Index.cshtml

```
<tbody>
   @foreach (var item in Model.vmKpiRecord) {
   <tr>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.kpiNo)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.kpiYear)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.kpiMonth)</td>
       <td>@getKpiWeek(item.kpiYear, item.kpiWeek)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.kpiValue)</td>
       <td>
           <a asp-action="DetailsRecord" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class=" btn btn-secondary">Details</a>
           <a asp-action="DeactivateRecord" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="btn btn-info">Deactivate</a>
           <a asp-action="DeleteRecord" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
       </td>
   </tr>
   }
</tbody>
```

kpiMaster table

[image]

kpiRecord table

[image]

Currently, my Index looks like this:

[image]

It needs to look like this instead:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables.

You can write a stored procedure in SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetKpiDetailedRecords]
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        KpiRecord R
        INNER JOIN KpiMaster M ON M.KpiNo = R.KpiNo

END
```

Or in your code with Linq:

```
var tables = new KpiViewModel {

    vmKpiDetailedRecords  = _context.kpirep_dev_kpiRecord.Where(kpiRecord => kpiRecord.isActive).Join(_context.kpirep_dev_kpiMaster,
    master => master.KpiNo, record => record.KpiNo,
    (record, master) => new {Kpi=master.KpiName,Year=record.KpiYear, ... }).ToList(),

    vmKpiGoal = _context.kpirep_dev_kpiGoal.Where(kpiGoal => kpiGoal.isActive).ToList()
};
```

Comment: Thanks, however now I get the error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<kpirep.Models.kpiDetailedRecord>

Comment: just change the => new {...} to new kpiDetailedRecord() {...}

Answer (score 1):

According to the table structure and data, the kpiRecord contains the foreign key ("kpiNo"), I suppose the kpiRecord Entity and kpiMaster Entity might be contains [the One-to-One or One-to-Many relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#other-relationship-patterns), right?

If the kpiRecord Entity contains an [navigation property](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/relationships#navigation-properties) (`public kpiMaster kpiMaster { get; set; }`), you could use the navigation properties in your model to load related entities, sample code as below:

```
public class kpirep_dev_kpiRecord
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime activeTimestamp { get; set; } 

    //... //other properties

    //used to configure one-to-one relationship.
    [ForeignKey("kpiMaster")]
    public int kpiNo { get; set; }
    public kpirep_dev_kpiMaster kpiMaster { get; set; } 

}

public class kpirep_dev_kpiMaster
{
    [Key]
    public int kpiNo { get; set; }
    public string kpiName { get; set; } 
}
```

In the Controller method, you could the **`Include()`** method to load the kpiMaster when query the kpiRecord.

```
        var tables = new KpiViewModel
        {
            //vmKpiMaster = _context.kpirep_dev_kpiMaster.ToList(),
            //vmKpiGoal = _context.kpirep_dev_kpiGoal.Where(kpiGoal => kpiGoal.isActive).ToList(),
            vmKpiRecord = _context.kpirep_dev_kpiRecord.Where(kpiRecord => kpiRecord.isActive).Include(c => c.kpiMaster).ToList()
        };

        return View(tables);
```

Then, in the View, using the following code to display the kpiName:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.vmKpiRecord)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.kpiMaster.kpiName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.kpiYear)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.kpiMonth)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.kpiValue)</td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="DetailsRecord" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class=" btn btn-secondary">Details</a>
                <a asp-action="DeactivateRecord" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="btn btn-info">Deactivate</a>
                <a asp-action="DeleteRecord" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

If you are not using the navigation property, you could use `join()` to join the table, then select the required properties. Then, display the result, you could refer to the following sample:

Create a ViewModel which contains the required properties(such as: kpiName):

```
public class kpiModelViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string kpiName { get; set; }
    public DateTime activeTimestamp { get; set; }
    public DateTime inactiveTimestamp { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public string submissionBy { get; set; }
    public int kpiNo { get; set; }
    public int kpiYear { get; set; }
    public int kpiMonth { get; set; }
    public int kpiWeek { get; set; }
    public int kpiValue { get; set; }
} 

public class KpiViewModel {

       //public IEnumerable<kpiMaster> vmKpiMaster { get; set; }
       //public IEnumerable<kpiGoal> vmKpiGoal { get; set; }
       //public IEnumerable<kpiModel> vmKpiRecord { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<kpiModelViewModel> vmKpiRecord { get; set; }
}
```

code in the controller:

```
        var tables = new KpiViewModel
        {
            //vmKpiMaster = _context.kpirep_dev_kpiMaster.ToList(),
            //vmKpiGoal = _context.kpirep_dev_kpiGoal.Where(kpiGoal => kpiGoal.isActive).ToList(),
            vmKpiRecord = _context.kpirep_dev_kpiRecord.Where(kpiRecord => kpiRecord.isActive)
            .Join(_context.kpirep_dev_kpiMaster, model => model.kpiNo, master => master.kpiNo, (model, master) => new { kModel = model, KMaster = master })
            .Select(ModelandMaster => new kpiModelViewModel()
            {
                kpiName = ModelandMaster.KMaster.kpiName,
                kpiYear = ModelandMaster.kModel.kpiYear,
                kpiWeek = ModelandMaster.kModel.kpiWeek,
                kpiValue = ModelandMaster.kModel.kpiValue
            }).ToList()
        };
        return View(tables);
```

Then, using the ViewModel to display the kpiName:

```
<tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.vmKpiRecord)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.kpiName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.kpiYear)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.kpiMonth)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.kpiValue)</td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="DetailsRecord" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class=" btn btn-secondary">Details</a>
                    <a asp-action="DeactivateRecord" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-info">Deactivate</a>
                    <a asp-action="DeleteRecord" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

The result like this:

[image]

Reference:

[Entity Framework Core One To One Relationships Conventions](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-one-relationship-configuration)

[Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

Answer (score 0):

In your Index view change:

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.kpiNo)</td>
```

to:

```
<td>@Html.DisplayHiddenFor(modelItem => item.kpiNo)</td>

<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.kpiName)</td>
```

and fix  theader  accordingly too.